# Ground-referenced current mirror with low voltage drop

Tags: ground, current-mirror

The following circuit produces a voltage v2 that is the logarithm of I[dut].  I've modeled it with I1 ranging from 1uA to 100mA and it does essentially what I want, but it could stand some improvement:

[image]

#### the theory

Q2,Q3 work as a current mirror so the emitter current on Q1 matches the current of the DUT.  And since Q1 is a diode-connected BJT, v2 is essentially log(I[dut]).  So far, so good.

#### the problem

For many applications, the voltage drop from Q2's Vbe (aka Vcc-v1) is not an issue: most DUT's we'll be working with have their own voltage regulator and are not sensitive to changes in voltage.

But to make this a more generally useful tool, I'd like to "stiffen" the voltage at v1, i.e. make it so changes in I1 have minimal effect on (Vcc-v1).

#### the ask

Is there an equivalent ground-referenced current mirror -- perhaps using an op-amp -- that replaces Q2 and Q3 and decreases changes in (Vcc-V1) as I1 changes?  One constraint: Vcc is the only voltage source available.

Comment: Could you explain why the voltage drop is a problem? Some solutions people give may depend on exactly what you need this circuit to do.

Comment: What’s the current range of I1?

Comment: Google "Howland current source".  Be careful of stability if you choose it -- I once worked at a company where it was popular with some designers, and made myself unpopular by referring to it as the "howlin' Howland".  Which was unfair, because with decent compensation it'll be as stable as you please.

Comment: I realize from the comments that my goal is not to reduce (Vcc-V1), but rather to make it "stiffer", i.e. reduce changes in (Vcc-V1) as I1 changes from 1uA to 100mA.  Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @TimWescott: Prof. Bradford Howland's elegant circuit is disqualified in this case, since the only voltage source available for an op-amp is Vcc -- the Howland circuit requires a wider voltage swing than the DUT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A board-level design of a current mirror requires heavy emitter degeneration to ensure current matching between branches due geometric/thermal mismatch of the BJTs.

A far more common board-level current mirror is constructed with sense resistors and an opamp servoing an output current source to match/scale the reference input current. A sample schematic is shown below.

[image]

Resistor \$R_1\$ samples the reference current. Opamp \$U_1\$ drives the base of PNP \$Q_1\$ to achieve an equivalent potential at lower terminal of \$R_2\$. This feedback action forces the current through \$R2\$ to be equal to the current through \$R_1\$.

The output current is taken at the collector. There is a small reduction in output current due to the finite \$\beta\$ of \$Q_1\$.

Comment: I'd use a PNP pair to get matching BJTs, but your op-amp solution has that built in.   It just requires an op-amp with good rail-to-rail performance.

Comment: Hello, yes, you can also substitute the pnp for a PMOS for an ever better matching ratio. If 100 mA is too large for your sense device you can change R2 to 10 Ohms for an output that is 1/10 the reference current.